# Disable Gantry caching

Tags: cache, gantry

I have a site using RocketTheme free template, and it`s using Gantry framework.

Now Ι need to add a page with some PHP code, so using **Sourcerer** I made a simple page using com_content and including my .php file there.

The problem is that Joomla caches content of my script. So I tried to disable Joomla cache, but that simple page loads so slow - thanks to RocketTheme and Gantry, with NO optimization.

So I decided to exclude caching of com_content component, but still cache header, footer and etc. I have installed JotCache, excluded com_component, excluded my page URL, but Gantry still caching it.

So, is there any way to disable Gantry caching? Or better way, is there any way so add some magic string to my file to stop caching it?

Comment: It might help to say which version of Gantry are you using.

Comment: I`m using Gantry v4.1.9

Comment: @TopClans have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

In order to increase the performance the Gantry stores Cache. It also stores modules and other joomla content. When you save template details it will automatically flush your template cache.

Comment: I thought it will be helpful but no issues I have removed that link.

Answer (score 1):

Gantry 4 cache can't be disabled as it's used to store compiled LESS and CSS files.

I suspect the Gantry 5 cache may be similar.